# How many paths on a grid $5×5$ coordinate grid with blocked coordinates and jumping positions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

On a $5×5$ coordinate plane, how many ways can you get from $(0,0)$ to $(5,5)$, moving only up and right, with these limitations:

- Coordinates $(2,1)$, $(3,2)$, and $(4,3)$ are blocked.
- Coordinates $(0,3)$ will jump you (or "teleport") to $(3,4)$

I'm sort of stuck with this problem.  Any help with a general formula, giving modified blocked or multiple jumping positions, would also be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Set up an equation system 5x5 = 25 unknowns, boundary condition = 1 way for upper / rightmost coordinates (9 equations). Other than that try encourage $v_{ij} = v_{i-1j} + v_{ij-1}$ everywhere except "special points". The special points may need some thinking, but I think you will figure something out.

Answer (score 1):

There are two standard approaches to this type of problem:

First, if there were no fancy obstacles, we could observe that you must take exactly $5$ steps up and exactly $5$ steps right, and there's $\binom{10}{5} = \frac{10!}{5!\,5!}$ ways to rearrange them. You can then deal with things such as blocked squares on a case-by-case basis: using this formula to count and then subtract the number of paths through $(2,1)$, and using inclusion-exclusion to deal with multiple obstacles, that sort of thing.

This is a good plan if there are few obstacles or they're regularly arranged in some way, or if the grid is large. But for a small grid with lots of fancy variants, the following method (which you could call dynamic programming if you like) works better.

Draw out the grid from $(0,0)$ to $(5,5)$:
$$\begin{matrix}
 ? & ? & ? & ? & ? & F \\
 ? & ? & ? & \boxed{?} & ? & ? \\
 \boxed{?} & ? & ? & ? & 0 & ? \\
 ? & ? & ? & 0 & ? & ? \\
 ? & ? & 0 & ? & ? & ? \\
 S & ? & ? & ? & ? & ? \\
\end{matrix}$$
(I've marked the start with $S$, the finish with $F$, the two teleports with boxes, and the blocked spaces with $0$.)

Then, starting from the start and working your way up, write down the number of paths from the start to that square in the grid, by the following rule: take the sum of the numbers in all spaces you could use to reach that square. So you'd begin:
$$\begin{matrix}
 ? & ? & ? & ? & ? & F \\
 ? & ? & ? & \boxed{?} & ? & ? \\
 \boxed{1} & ? & ? & ? & 0 & ? \\
 1 & 3 & ? & 0 & ? & ? \\
 1 & 2 & 0 & ? & ? & ? \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ? & ? \\
\end{matrix}$$
The number you write down in the square marked $F$ is the final answer.